# Task/Job Failed on Mesos

Tags: apache-spark, task, mesos, spark-submit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqLqt.png)

Anyone know why every task/job that I run using spark submit on my apache Mesos cluster is always STATE FAILED? For your information, I using spark mesos dispatcher to run cluster mode and spark submit to run the job.
Is it possible the effect of too little total disk? If yes, how to increase the capacity of the disk? or is there another problem?

Comment: Do you have any logs or access to mesos UI where you should be able to see the reason why task failed?

Comment: The problem is solve. I already know how to see the log and solve the problem, but another problem are coming